# Constructing a search form in Django

Tags: php, python, django, forms

I am trying to build a search form in Django, but unfortunately I cannot get the code to work as the textbook said it would (I am using The Django Book). I couldn't get the form to submit, so I added a button, which fixed that. Unfortunately, now I cannot get the form to carry out the search function in views. It just gives me a 404 error.

Below, please find the template,

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Search</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action=“/search/“ method = “get”>
        <input type = “text” name = “q”>
       < button type = “submit”> Submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please excuse the lack of brackets. I couldn't figure out how to get the site not to interpret it as HTML.

the view,

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def search_form(request):
    return render(request, "search_form.html")
def search(request):
    if 'q' in request.GET:
        message = "You searched for: %r" % request.GET['q']
    else:
        message = "You submitted an empty form."
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

the URLconf,
    from django.conf.urls import include, url
    from django.contrib import admin
    from mysite2.views import hello, current_datetime, hours_ahead
    from books import views

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^hello/$', hello),
    url(r'^time/$', current_datetime),
    url(r'^time/plus/(\d{1,2})/$', hours_ahead),
    url(r'^search-form/$', views.search_form),
    url(r'^search/$', views.search),
 ]
```

and the error page.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/search-form/%E2%80%9C/search/%E2%80%9C?%E2%80%9Cq%E2%80%9D=A+Really+Good+Book
Using the URLconf defined in mysite2.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^hello/$
^time/$
^time/plus/(\d{1,2})/$
^search-form/$
^search/$
The current path, search-form/“/search/“, didn't match any of these.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your form attributes should use straight quotes `"`, not curly quotes `“` or `”`.

```
<form action="/search/" method="get">
    <input type = "text" name = "q">
```

Your error message `search-form/“/search/“` suggests that your code really does contain `“`, and it's not just a problem in your Stack Overflow question.

Comment: How do I get the straight quotes?

Comment: That depends on your text editor, I can't help you with that.